# How can tab settings be configured for individual source attachments or libraries, in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, editor, tabs, settings

We all know that we can configure tab (code format) settings globally in Eclipse, and we can also do it per project. We often go to the source of JDK classes when debugging, or writing. If you set Eclipse's global preferences to the Java standard format, the JDK source code looks right. If you use any other preferences globally (like a company standard, or the Eclipse standard), the Java source looks like crap because of its embedded hard tabs.

Is there any way to configure the tab settings for a source attachment, or for a library?

It's a little weird that I'm not finding references to this issue. Maybe everyone switches to the Java standard format, then uses project-specific format settings.

Or maybe there's just something I missed, somewhere. Is there?

Answer (score 0):

If you use jadclipse there is an option to use eclipse format settings [image]

Comment: I think what you're saying here is that this plugin will use existing source code, if it finds it, and then passes that source through the code formatter. That would solve the problem. I'll give it a try.